# GLES fragment shader, get 0-1 range when using TextureRegion - libGDX

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I have a fragment shader in which I use v_texCoords as a base for some effects. This works fine if I use a single Texture, as v_texCoords always ranges from 0 - 1, so the center point is always (0.5, 0.5) for example. If I am drawing from part of a TextureRegion though, my shader messes up because v_texCoords no longer ranges from 0-1. Is there any methods or variabels I can use to get a consistent 0-1 range in my fragment shader? I want to avoid setting uniforms as this would mean I need to flush the batch for every draw.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like this exists at the shader level - `TextureRegions` are entirely a libgdx construct that doesn't exist at all at the OpenGL ES API level.

Honestly for what you are trying I'd simply suggest not overloading the texture coordinate for two orthogonal purposes, and just add a separate vertex attribute which provides the 0-to-1 number.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you give an example for the vertex attribute please?

Comment: Not really - it depends on your models, and how you are using libgdx. All you want is a parallel attribute to your `texCoords` attribute, with the scaled 0-to-1 values.